# Why two .wav that should have the same pitch don't

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, signal-processing, physics, acoustics

This is for a python computational physics class. We are given two .wav files that contain files of a harp and a piano playing the same note. We are supposed to "load the files and take the FFT of the amplitude. From the FFT determine the frequency of the fundamental for both instruments to 4 sig figs."

Here is what I have done.

```
import scipy.io.wavfile as sciwav
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#import data from .wav file. This function returns the sampling rate and the data in an array.
harp_rate,harp_data=sciwav.read('/Users/williamweiss2/Desktop/Test2/harp.wav',mmap=False)
piano_rate,piano_data=sciwav.read('/Users/williamweiss2/Desktop/Test 2/piano.wav',mmap=False)
#perform the FFT on both sets of data and graph to find the index of the first harmonic.
plt.figure(1)
p=rfft(piano_data)
h=rfft(harp_data)
plt.subplot(121)
plot(abs(p),'b')
title('Piano FFT')
xlim(0,100000)
plt.subplot(122)
plot(abs(h),'g')
title('Harp FFT')
```

This all works just fine. Now, to find freq. of note played this is what I was taught to do.

x value of first spike in FFT graph = Index.

deltaF = Sampling Rate / # of samples.

Index * deltaF = Freq. of note played.

I followed these steps and got two drastically different notes. Does anyone see a misstep in my process? Any ideas are appreciated even if they go over my head. I am just a junior getting a Physics degree. Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: I think that the right equation are `max(abs(rfft(bin_from_fft)))*destaF/len(fftsize)`

Comment: @ederwander When a print the result from the equation you gave me, I get this error `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`. Any ideas why?

Comment: @ederwander OP's equation for an FFT bin's frequency is correct.

Comment: @W.Weiss edit your question and put your code...